# Problem with textfield - J2ME Polish

Tags: j2mepolish

```
//#style term 
term = new TextField("Term", "", TextField.ANY, 50);
```

And this CSS:

```
.term
{
  textfield-direct-input: true;
  border-color: black;
  font-size: small;
  font-color: black;
  layout: left;
  title-position: top;
  background: none;
  padding: 10;
  margin: 10;
  include-label: true;
  text-layout: left; 
  text-wrap: false;
}
```

But when I start emulator, in the textfield I can write only two characters...I don´t know why  Please help, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
//#style term
term = new TextField("Term", "", 50, TextField.ANY);
```